# Undefined result in MongoDB and Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I want to get my collection data, my collection is named `students` and is part of my `pool` database.

The connection to the mongoDB works, however `console.log(result.lastname)` returns `undefined`.

Here is my `server.js` file

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var assert = require('assert');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';

mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {

     if(err) {
         console.log("Connection failed");
    }
    console.log("Connection successfull");

    var dbo = db.db("pool");

    dbo.collection("students").find({}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result.lastname);
        db.close();
      });

});
```

And the content in my `students` collection that I see using `db.students.find();` directly in console

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb1570f2c0167c90cc127fd"), "id" : 0, "lastname" : "Sam", "firstname" : "Sung", "email" : "sc@mail.com", "phone" : 613295990, "validated" : "Validated", "admin" : true }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this link:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

`.find()` returns a list and not just one entry. Meaning even though your collection has one entry, it will be received as a list with just one entry.
You have to iterate.
So, try this:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var assert = require('assert');
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';

mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {

     if(err) {
         console.log("Connection failed");
    }
    console.log("Connection successfull");

    var dbo = db.db("pool");

    dbo.collection("students").find({}, function(err, result).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result.lastname);
        db.close();
      });

});
```

Another helpful link : https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_find.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think it is returning an array, can you try:

```
result[0].lastname
```